# SELECT => IMAP4rev1 Server logging out Trying to Log in to Yahoo Mail

Tags: imap

I'm trying at access the Yahoo Mail IMAP. My script logs in, fetches emails then logs out again. It then pauses for 1 second before logging in again.

It works ok for about 10 minutes then starts giving this error when trying to log back in:

```
SELECT => IMAP4rev1 Server logging out
```

After which I can no longer log in.

I have looked through the docs but cannot see any mention of rate limits.

Does anyone know what the issue is?

Comment: Most likely the server is protecting itself from being hammered.  Yahoo really doesn’t want you to be hammering the server.  Change your backoff to more like 5 minutes.

Comment: Thanks @Max. I didn't think that would count as hammering. It replicates what, for example, the Yahoo Android app and others do.

Comment: That is almost assuredly not true.  The Yahoo app may not be using IMAP at all, and if it is, it has access to an out-of-band push channel (using android or ios push services) that third party apps do not have access to (I believe the IMAP CAPABILITY for this is XYMPUSHSERVICE, but it is private and undocumented).  If it were true, that Yahoo app would be sucking battery like no tomorrow, keeping the network connection busy continuously.

Comment: Despite IMAP4_SSL.fetch() -ing from Yahoo server once in 60 seconds it logs me out in an hour sharp. The only way to continue I'm aware of is to create the new IMAP4_SSL obj, do login(), then select(). Tested the day of the post.